# Inspect JVM asm Code in Intelli J IDEA

Tags: java, assembly, disassembly

One of the nice feature of Visual Studio debugger is that one can look at the JIT generated machine code by pressing CTRL-F11. I am trying to find a similar feature to inspect JVM generated machine code in Intelli J IDEA when I am debugging a program. Does anyone know?

Note that I want to look at the actual native machine code shown as ASM. This is not the byte code generated by the Java compiler.

Comment: Java is compiled into the machine code for the the Java CPU(JASM). Intellij will show you that. It seems you want the machine code for a non java CPU. Which is pointless, as any Java virtual machine(JVM) will translate the JASM using it's own idiosyncrasies, and then ther is the point where you are probably using an x64 cpu and most java code is executed on non x64 machines.

Comment: This is not pointless. It provides valuable clues on why the program performs like this for specific JVM and hardware.  I only care about the performance of this specific piece of code running on this specific of hardware and JVM. A slightly different JVM or hardware will change things, but the change is likely small.

Comment: High Performance JVM's are not simple code translators. They take into account how often the particular piece of code has already run, the current state of the machine it is running on, how likely the code is to run again, how similar this piece of code is to other pieces of code in the system along with other factors. The same JVM on the same machine with the same switches could produce vastly different "native" code for the same piece of byte code for 2 different executions.

Comment: If you are interested in performance tuning this site may be of value, http://www.javaperformancetuning.com.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, understanding a particular translation at a particular moment can still be valuable.

Comment: there is the VM switch `-XX:+PrintOptoAssembly` which is available on some VMS you will probably need to build OpneJDK8 yourself to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible - when working in the IDE only bytecode is generated. Actual machine code is only produced by the JIT compiler (which is part of the JRE, not IntelliJ) at runtime.

The JIT compilation process also will vary (potentially a lot) from run to run and may well produce very different machine code depending on the details of the host it is executed on.

What is it you're looking to find out?

Comment: It should be possible to show the machine code in the IDE when debugging the program. I am looking to find out how the JVM compiles specific language constructs to do low level optimization.  A different JVM or even the same JVM on different hardware is likely to generate different machine code, but the difference is likely small and I still think there is value.